# Get data in Angular Material modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-material

I am getting data via `get` request. Now, on click of a button, I want to open the `angular material` modal and show that data.
Here's my code:

```
$scope.openModal = function(event) {
    $http.get('/my/api', null).then(
        function(data) { $scope.arr=data; },
        function(err) { console.log(err); }
    );

    $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: '/app/modal.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: event,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
    });       
}
```

In the template, I have a table and I want to display the `arr` data. It's working fine if I make the get request outside the click handler.

Comment: Could you please specify what is your problem exactly , you are saying its working fine if you make the get request outside the click handler can you please define it more so that it can be easily understood Thanks

Comment: Is the issue that the modal is loading before the promise has resolved? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: You want to use the `resolve` for this.

Comment: @Parveenyadav in the case discussed here, i am getting an empty array

Comment: @Lex modal is loading before i guess

Answer (score 0):

If the only issue is that your `arr` variable doesn't have the expected result, it is likely because the parameter on the success function of `.then()` is an object that contains your data in a `.data` property. So you need to use:

```
$http.get('/my/api', null).then(
    function(response) { $scope.arr = response.data; },
    function(err) { console.log(err); }
);
```

If you need to delay loading of the modal until the call to your API is resolved then you can simply put that code inside the same function where you are setting `$scope.arr`.

Comment: on console.log(arr) , i get the data, but the template html of the modal only gets the scope variable values outside the openModal function